# Using Index in ArrayList to edit object

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the first code which is the Person Class:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(String name,int age){
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name+","+age;
    }

}
```

Then this is the main class wherein it will show the output:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PersonDatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> list= new ArrayList<>();
        Person p = new Person("",0);
        int choice =0;
        String listing ="";

        do{
            choice=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\nChoices:"+"\n[1]Add"+"\n[2]Edit"+"\n[3]Delete"+"\n[4]Search"+"\n[5]View"+"\n[6]Sort"+"\n[7]Exit"+"\nEnter Choice:"));


            switch(choice){
            case 1:
                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\nEnter Name:");
                int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\nEnter Age:"));
                list.add(new Person(name,age)); 
                break;

            case 2:
                try{
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter index value:"));
                    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Name:");
                    age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Age:"));
                    list.set(index,name,age);

                }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Index");
                }

                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:
                if(!list.isEmpty()){
                    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                        listing+=list.get(i).toString()+"\n";
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,listing);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR","", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                break;

            case 7:
                break;


            }

        }while(choice!=7);
    }

}
```

how do you use index so that you can search the object you inputted and then edit it using list.set()

Comment: you should not add the code from answers to the OP. It will confuse the future readers of the post.

Answer (score 3):

Create the `Person` instance and then set it to the index.

```
list.set(index,name,age);
```

instead use

```
list.set(index,new Person(name,age));
```

You are already doing the same in `add()` method, while adding the `Person`s to the list. It is same, just use the `set()` method.

---

The issue is that, you are not resetting the `listing` each time `view` is called. In the start of the `view` you can reset it to the empty string. Add the below lines.

```
case 5:
   listing = "";
```

Comment: when I try to get the output it only adds but not edit the object

Comment: did you update the code provide in the answer above. It should do. list.set(index, element) -> `Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.`

Comment: Make the changes in your code locally and run it. It should work.

Comment: when I only have one object inputted I can edit it but when I add another object then edit it it will only make a new object but not edit the index value I specified

Comment: put some sout and debug it. like what is the value of index or size of list currently.

Comment: I am able to test is successfully.

Comment: still can't get it right when I try your suggestion when I add an object then edit it I can change it but when I try to add another object then edit again it  the second object just duplicates itself

Comment: I have got the issue and updated the post. Please check.

Comment: I found a new problem the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

If you know the index `i` of the `Person` object, `list.get(i)` will get you the object which you can modify in place. Since your `Person` object is *mutable*, you can do this:

```
Person p = list.get(i);
p.setName(name);
p.setAge(age);
```

This works because `p` refers to the same `Person` object as stored inside the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead edit by searching the username. By doing that, the application can guarantee that there will be no `IndexOutOfBoundException`. How?
In `case 2`, first get the entered username. Then loop through the list to find him. Once found, use `list.get(i)` to get the user, edit it, and break the loop.